Не работает отладка python-кода в VS Code (не останавливается на точках останова)
При запуске кода в режиме отладки (F5) он не останавливается на точках останова, а просто отрабатывает как обычно.
Мой launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Отладчик Python: Текущий файл",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

Пробовал:

Полная переустановка VS Code
Откат расширений Python и Python Debugger до старых версий (Python - до версии 2024.22.0, Python Debugger - до версии 2024.14.0)
Добавлять в launch.json строку "stopOnEntry": true (для остановки при входе в программу)

Ничего из этого не решило проблему. Что еще можно сделать?

Вы используете нативные потоки ОС?

@maestro, я проверял все на простейших скриптах без многопоточности, по типу a = 5, b = 10, print(a + b)

Когда вы нажимаете F5, в консоли появляется команда. Покажите её текст.

@maestro, PS D:\SOFT\Python\my_scripts\cb_tracking>  d:; cd 'd:\SOFT\Python\my_scripts\cb_tracking'; & 'd:\SOFT\Python\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Vano\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.15.2024121701-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\launcher' '64085' '--' 'D:\SOFT\Python\my_scripts\cb_tracking\gui.py'

Командная строка правильная. Больше у меня нет идей, почему может не работать.
